# How can I guarantee correct partitioning in this Quicksort 3-way partition implementation?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, quicksort

I am trying to implement a Quicksort algorithm with three-way partioning, which is mentioned as one way to speed up the sorting algorithm when there are only a few unique elements. I found the following implementation based on the 'Dutch Flag Problem' online but I noticed that it does not partition the array correctly for certain cases.

```cpp
void partition3(vector<int> &a, int low, int high, int &i, int &j) {
    int mid = low;
    int pivot = a[high];
    while (mid <= high) {
        if (a[mid] < pivot)
            swap(a[low++], a[mid++]);
        else if (a[mid] == pivot)
            mid++;
        else if (a[mid] > pivot)
            swap(a[mid], a[high--]);
    }
 
    // update i and j
    i = low - 1;
    j = mid; 
}
```

for the input case where `a = [2,3,9,2,2]` the resulting partitioned array is `a'=[2,2,2,9,3]`. In this particular case when the last element is selected as the pivot point there is never a case where `a[mid] < pivot` and therefore pointer `low` is never incremented. As such the partitioning algorithm outputs pivot point `i=-1` and `j=3`.

How should the initial pivot be selected such that the input array will be partitioned correctly?

The algorithm above fits into `Quicksort` as follows:

```cpp
void threeway_quick_sort(vector<int> &a, int l, int r) {
  if (l >= r) {
    return;
  }

  int m1 = 0 , m2 = 0; 
  partition3(a, l, r, m1, m2); //compute partition points m1 and m2 for 3 way split 

  randomized_quick_sort(a, l, m1 - 1); //recursively sort the lower array
  randomized_quick_sort(a, m2 + 1, r); //recursively sort the upper array 
}
```

where `l=0` and `r=a.size()-1`

Comment: Your array seems to be partitioned correctly, with the left partition empty.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI thanks, I was missing in my understanding that the partition can also be empty.